# Visual Studio generated binaries

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Need quick help from win developers. Please correct me where I got it wrong. Thank you!

I built a C++ library from the source code and got the following files:

***.dll.** These go into a folder listed in the **PATH** environment variable.

***.lib.** These go into a folder where Visual Studio searches for libraries.

***.pdb.** These are needed for debugging. Copy them alongside DLL files or 
LIB files?

***.exp.** No clue what do to with these ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to debug the library on the same computer where you built it, you don't need to move .pdb files at all. Otherwise put them along with the .dll. You might also need to strip the full paths to pdb from the dll using the /PDBALTPATH option.
You probably won't need the .exp files at all, since you're using a third-party library that probably does not import from your project.

Comment: Thanks! How about static libraries. I get LIB and PDB files, but no DLL files. Where should I copy PDB files?

Comment: Along with the .lib files, but it might be a little trickier. OpenSSL and Google Protobuffers do so though.